# Can a blocking creature fight? How is damage dealt if it dies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

As the title says, can a blocking creature fight? If so, what happens if the blocking creature dies before damage is dealt? How would damage be dealt during combat?

Example: Creature A is a 2/2 and it is blocking creature B, which is also 2/2. Before combat damage, I cast an instant forcing creature A to fight creature C, another 2/2, so that both A and C die.

Comment: It does not sound like fighting really has anything to do with the question at-hand; the question is about what happens if a blocking creature dies before combat damage is dealt.

Comment: @Gendolkari The original question was *"Can a blocking creature fight? If so, what happens if it dies before damage is dealt?"* The revised question is *"What happens if it dies before damage is dealt?"* Part of the original question was lost in your edit, and so I added it back.

Comment: Given the grammar/formatting, it was hard to know the intention, but I assumed (maybe incorrectly) that "fighting" in this case was simply the way in which the creature died. But as worded now, it really should be asked as 2 separate questions, and both of them should be closed as duplicates anyway.

Comment: Agreed about the double-duplicate thing; the question definitely seemed to be "do fight and combat interact?" along with "what happens if a blocker goes away?" (That's what I was trying to suggest in my first comment; I just didn't vote initially because I didn't want to close it as a duplicate of only one question and hadn't found the best candidate for the other.)

Answer (score 4):

If you cast such an instant after declaring blockers, the following will happen:

Your creature A will fight creature C and they will both die. Creature B will still be blocked, and thus will not deal any damage to you unless it has trample.